# Check if valid url WebView Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to check if the video url works before embedding it into my webView.  Because if the user enters a url that doesn't resolve or contain video then the webView will display a whitebox

```
  // (if MyVariables.link is valid)
  {....
  let Code:NSString = "<iframe width=\(width) height=\(height) src=\(MyVariables.link)  frameborder=\(frame)></iframe>";
  self.wView.loadHTMLString(Code as String, baseURL: nil)
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the url by using `canOpenURL` from `UIApplication`

```
 if let url = NSURL(string: yourUrlString) {
    var canOpen = UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)
 }
```

Comment: Edited my answer. The return doesn't work if your method doesn't return a bool. So you can save your information in canOpen and check this variable.