# How to check if Link is broken with WKWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, wkwebview

I use `WKWebview` to load a URL.

```
let webView = WKWebview()
let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

**How can I detect if the link the webView should load is broken?**

Comment: did you try to encrypt the url before you make the request to avoid broken characters like spaces and "#'.. etc ?

Comment: @Manch How do I do this encryption part?

Comment: Sorry, i mean encode the url, so take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/24552028/4194908

Comment: @Manch Why should I encode the url?

Comment: maybe your url has spaces, or '#' or anything may lead your url not able to make the request.

Comment: @Manch Should I always encode URLS before opening then?

Comment: yes, by this you will avoid broken url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if valid url WebView Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229697/check-if-valid-url-webview-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `canOpenUrl` method:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)
```

It will do the url validation and if the link is ok it returns true.
It's mostly use before you call:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

to make sure this link can be open in safari but it should help you here too.

Make sure the link starts with http:// or https://.

Edited:

It will just check is the link is a correct url.

If you want to see the page is offline, authorisation issues, etc. you can implement `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol and check out this method:

```
- webView:didFailNavigation:withError:
```

this should give you more info.

It's always good idea to use: `str.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAl‌​lowedCharacterSet())!`
it make sure that you don't pass a character which are not allowed in URL.

Edited 2:
To detect the status code you can try to implement:

```
- webView:decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:decisionHandler:
```

the navigation response is an `NSURLResponse` instance but 
whenever you make an HTTP request, the `NSURLResponse` object you get back is actually an instance of the `NSHTTPURLResponse` class so you should cast it to `NSHTTPURLResponse`. That should give you a `statusCode`.
In the last line in the method you should call handler, for example `decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicyAllow)`.

Comment: Assume the link is a correct url. The target page could be offline. How do I check that?

Comment: would you also suggest encoding each url before calling like it is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url/24552028#24552028

Comment: @confile yes I wold. You don't want to pass a character which are not allowed in URL. I would use: str.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!

Comment: Could you please add this to your answer.

Comment: But what if the server respond with 404 how do I detect this?

Comment: @confile check out the error in - webView:didFailNavigation:withError: method.

Comment: When I get a 404 there is no error and webView:didFailNavigation:withError is not called because of the redirect.

Comment: @confile please see edited code. I haven't tried this but I believe that should work. Let me know if it's not so I will remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ref: [Answer exists here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229697/check-if-valid-url-webview-swift)

```
if let url = NSURL(string: yourUrlString) {
    var canOpen = UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if url string is correct and valid - just create `NSURL` object, if path contains error it will cast to `nil`:

```
let string = "http://google.com"
let url = NSURL(string: string)

let brokenString = "http:\\brokenurl.12"
let brokenUrl = NSURL(string: brokenString) // nil - it's not valid!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented NSURLConnectionDelegate then below solution can be used.

**didFailWithError** method of **NSURLConnectionDelegate** can be used for this.

This method get called if an error occurs during the loading of a resource.

Can refer to below link
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnectiondelegate/1418443-connection